# При наведении курсора на элемент прокручивание приостанавливалось

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var marquee = $("#marquee"); 
marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});

marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
marquee.find("span").css({
  "width": "50%",
  "display": "inline-block",
  "text-align": "center"
}); 
marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone());

marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");

var reset = function() {
  $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
  $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 25000, 'linear', reset);
};

reset.call(marquee.find("div"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="string">
  <div id="marquee" style="float:left;" >
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEirx.jpg" height="100" style="float:left;" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IkA6.png" height="100" style="float:left;" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzYHm.png" height="100" style="float:left;" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var marquee = $("#marquee"); 
marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});

marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
marquee.find("span").css({
  "width": "50%",
  "display": "inline-block",
  "text-align": "center"
}); 
marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone());

marquee.wrapInner("<div>");
marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");

   var reset = function() {
   $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
            $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 25000, 'linear', reset);
            $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).stop();
            }, function() {
                            
            $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 25000, 'linear', reset);
            });
};
        reset.call(marquee.find("div"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>


<div class="string">
  <div id="marquee" style="float:left;" >
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEirx.jpg" height="100" style="float:left;" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IkA6.png" height="100" style="float:left;" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzYHm.png" height="100" style="float:left;" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```